# Can't switch to iframe and close the frame in Selenium using Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, iframe, selenium-chromedriver

After multiple unsuccessful attempts to try and grab details from the website (https://www.chemist.co.uk/) I realized that there is an iframe that appears after a few seconds and that the event only happens once, when the website is opened. However, I find it difficult to handle the iframe, I tried various methods like finding the iframe based on index and id as well, as the iframe has no name. From my observation this only happens once I open the website. Can someone help me figure out what am I doing wrong?

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
currentdir = os.getcwd()


chrome_options = Options()
# chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')    
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=f"{currentdir}/chromedriver.exe", options=chrome_options)
# driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
driver.get("https://www.chemist.co.uk/")
time.sleep(5)
# driver.switch_to.frame(1)
iframe = driver.find_element_by_id("AWIN_CDT")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@data-trigger='dismiss.close']").click()
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using time.sleep use explicit wait for iFrame to appear and then switch to it. Also there are four `iframes` in your page. And the pop up is not inside the iframe with ID as `AWIN_CDT` rather it is inside 2nd frame with below infomation:

```
<iframe scrolling="no" style="border: none; height: 1px; width: 100%; min-height: 100%; display: inline !important;"></iframe>
```

So in order to close the pop up you need to switch to this frame.

```
driver.get('https://www.chemist.co.uk/')
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[contains(@style,'border: none; height')]")))
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@data-trigger='dismiss.close']").click()
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

You need to **import** below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: How did you figure out the iframe however? I tried it multiple times but could only see one of it. Now that you mentioned that the iframe is different I realized I was looking at the wrong iframe. Thanks anyways.

Comment: It’s a little brute technique :P.  If you search for your element in inspection mode such as //iframe[ <valid path>]//<elementXpath>. It should give me match. I am sure this is not very stubble way of doing but it works.

Comment: Well, given the fact that double digit iframes in a single webpage is unusual, that a decent approach I guess.

Answer (score 1):

The pop up element present inside an `iframe` which you need to switch it first. However the element is not present the `iframe` you have identified.

Induce `WebDriverWait()` and wait for `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it`() and below `xpath`.

Induce `WebDriverWait()` and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`() and below `xpath`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.chemist.co.uk/")
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"(//iframe[@scrolling='no'])[last()]")))
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[@data-trigger='dismiss.close']"))).click()
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Browser snapshot after clicking the popup.

[image]

Comment: I tried this too, thanks for the idea. What I noticed what the scraper fails to start 2-3 times out of 10 times. In the non headless mode, I figured that it has something to do with clicking the close button of the iframe as the browser was still waiting after the iframe occurred. Thanks

Comment: Not sure why it is failing at your end.I have run multiple times my code and it never failed.

Comment: Do you think it could be because of the internet connection? because when I tried it what basically happens is, if the website loads as usual, it's well and good working fine but if the website fails to load immediately driver.implicitly_wait(15) is delaying the process for 15 seconds I believe. Sorry I forgot to mention it here but I used it in my script.

Comment: You don’t need implicitly wait.Just copy and paste my entire code and let me know the status how this goes.

Comment: I am just beginning my script with this part, I am trying to webscrape the product details of all the products on the website, so I might need it. Do you ever use implicitly wait? or is WebDriverWait is always your go to method?